# Thread safety in VB6 from C# dll library

Tags: multithreading, vb6, thread-safety

I have a little problem with visual basic 6 project. Everything works fine in the IDE but the executable crashes every time, when I run the application. The application uses callbacks to communicate with a .Net dll. Even code as simple as showing a from when the callback starts.
I changed the compilation mode to P-Code and still the problem persist.
Any help would be appreciate.
Thank you all

VB6 Code:

```
  Option Explicit

  Public foo As FOOClient.foo
  Public comWrapper As FOOClient.comWrapper

  Sub Start()
      Set foo = New FOOClient.foo
      Set comWrapper = New FOOClient.comWrapper

      Set foo = comWrapper.SpiInit()
      comWrapper.Main foo, AddressOf TxFlowStateChanged, AddressOf PairingFlowStateChanged
      foo.Start

      PrintStatusAndActions
  End Sub

  Private Sub TxFlowStateChanged(ByVal e As FOOClient.TransactionFlowState)
      frmActions.Show

      PrintFlowInfo e

      PrintStatusAndActions
  End Sub

  Private Sub PairingFlowStateChanged(ByVal e As FOOClient.PairingFlowState)
      frmActions.Show

      frmActions.listFlow.Clear
      frmActions.lblFlowMessage.Caption = e.Message

      If e.ConfirmationCode <> "" Then
          frmActions.listFlow.AddItem "# Confirmation Code: " + e.ConfirmationCode
      End If

      PrintStatusAndActions
  End Sub
```

Comment: if you vote negative please ask me. I can explain what you don't understand

Comment: Please can you provide us some code ? Do you have error managment (on error ... in VB6, and try...catch in c#) ? I guess you have been downvoted because your question lacks of details regarding the code and the process between your VB6 project and your C# DLL.

Comment: I want to learn how to get thread-safety in VB6. I need an example of it

Comment: VB6 has very little support for threads to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C# library can use threads, but it must never call back into the VB6-based EXE on any thread but the main GUI thread that VB6 started.  You can use Control.Invoke and Control.BeginInvoke (among other methods) to dispatch callbacks back into VB6.   (It is OK to create a Control instance in your library for this purpose, just be sure it is created on the first calling thread from the VB6-based EXE.)

Comment: Thanks for answer, Can you share an example ?

Comment: Not a lot of VB6 stuff laying around handy, that was a while ago.  Post an abbreviated snippet of code of the C# class and method you are calling into, and be sure that it includes the code that calls back to VB6 and then we all can go from there.